# Approximate the value of the derivative from the table.

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

[image]

How to find the value of the derivative at the point $0$ ? Should I find the average of  forward , backward and central differences at the point $0$ ?

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practical work,
I have used
$f'(x)
\approx \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
$.

In this case,
that is
$f'(0)
\approx \dfrac{1.2-1}{.2}
=1
$.

Comment: So I need not find the forward and backward differences? @marty cohen

Comment: Not in my experience.